# React Native: How to add Icons on createBottomNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview

I want to add icons on my bottom navigator but I don't know how or where to put it. Can someone help me? I'm currently learning react native so please bear with me. Thank you!.

[screenshot of bottom navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1iMe.jpg)

Here is my code for navigation:

```
    import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
    import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
    import SignInScreen from "./src/screens/SignInScreen";
    import SignUpScreen from "./src/screens/SignUpScreen";
    import RestaurantScreen from "./src/screens/RestaurantScreen";
    import RestaurantDetailScreen from "./src/screens/RestaurantDetailScreen";
    import MapScreen from "./src/screens/MapScreen";
    import MyDealsScreen from "./src/screens/MyDealsScreen";
    import { setNavigator } from "./src/navigationRef";
    import Header from "./src/components/Header";
    import React from "react";

    const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signin: SignInScreen,
    Signup: SignUpScreen,
     }),
    mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    List: createStackNavigator({
      RestaurantList: RestaurantScreen,
      RestaurantDetail: RestaurantDetailScreen,
    }),
    Map: MapScreen,
    MyDeals: MyDealsScreen,
    }),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this please check official document for [reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#example)

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={Feed}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
          tabBarBadge: 3,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```